# Añadir marca de agua a PDF con AspPDF

Tags: pdf, asp

He generado un fichero llamemoslo  `test.pdf`, quiero integrarle una marca de agua con un archivo `imagen.png`.

Mi fichero asp

> marcadeagua.asp:

```
<% Set Pdf1 = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Pdf")
Set Doc1 = Pdf1.OpenDocument( Server.MapPath("test.pdf") )

' Draw background image on all 3 remaining pages
Set Image1 = Doc1.OpenImage( Server.MapPath("imagen.png") )
For Each Page1 in Doc1.Pages
   Page1.Background.DrawImage Image1, "x=0, y=0; scalex=1; scaley=1"
Next
```

Me devuelve un error diciendo que:

`Object required: 'Doc1'`

Mi fichero pdf esta con una contraseña que envio al usuario anteriormente.
¿Como puedo abrir correctamente el fichero con contraseña?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun la [documentación de AspPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/manual.html) , solo tenía que añadir como parametro la contraseña:

EJ:

```
Set Doc1 = Pdf1.OpenDocument( Server.MapPath("test.pdf"), contraseña )
```